# Python: Can't import cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I have a simple Python program that tries to import cv2, but fails.

```
  File "/home/userJB/HelloWorld.py", line 4, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/home/userJB/srcMisc/Python-2.7.13/INSTALL/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import cv2
ImportError: cannot import name cv2
```

Where should I start looking to resolve this?  I have installed a local version on python on this machine.  I have also installed openCV on this machine.  I might not have fully installed openCV correctly.  Do I need to do anything else to build/install a cv2 module?

Comment: What type of OS do you have?

Comment: Sorry.  This is an ubuntu-like lunux OS.

Comment: SUSE-like, not ubuntu-like.

Comment: As per http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/ `cv2` if installed properly would be in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Did you install as per this documentation?

Comment: I don't have root access on this machine.  So, I can not install in /usr/local.